# Where are BirdNET saved observation sound snippets saved on an iPhone?

Tags: air, bird, birdnet

I've recorded some sounds using the app BirdNET (https://birdnet.cornell.edu/) and would like to share/export some of the recorded observations I made and saved. I cannot find them within my iPhone's folder structure. Is anyone familiar with where these are saved by default or how to extract them?

Comment: If anyone has the answer for android phones, it would be helpful to hear their answer too :)

Comment: Could find folders on Android phone (cache and files) but they remain empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I have found is to save them individually to a separate folder you create.  Choose the sound you want from the observation list, hit the icon in top right to choose an application and it will give you option to Save to Files. From there, I go to the 'On My Phone' directory. There is an option in the upper right corner to create a new folder, which I create to keep organized. Then hit save.

I don't know of a way to batch save if you already have a lot of observations, but at least you will be able to get them off your phone as a directory.

I have no idea where Birdnet stores the files by default, probably within the application. You're not alone with the frustration level of trying to find them :)

Comment: I gave this a try and it seems like a workable solution. I still wonder if I now have two copies taking up room on my phone (the default save location and my new manual folder) but this is what I will do for now!

Answer (score 10):

In Android, if you:

1. Open up the menu
2. Go to "show observations"
3. Select an observation
4. Select "share"
5. Save to google drive
6. download from drive onto a desktop PC
7. Add ".wav" to the end of the file name

You will end up with a usable file. It's a bit of a kludgy process but it did end up with a usable file that I was able to open up in Audacity to confirm it'd play back. The same general workflow may be possible with an iPhone and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I've posted answer on the [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249544/how-to-backup-birdnet/253651#253651):

It is possible to export and import all observations in the BirdNET application now:

☰ > Show observations > ⋮ > Export Observations

[image]